# Separate Single XML Value into multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have table in below format,

```
MENUACTION         VALUE

ReceivedDetails    <KEY /><ACCOUNTNO v="3275402GBP" /><AGR1 /><AGR2 /><PAY1 /><PAY2>
```

I need the table in below format

```
MENUACTION         VALUE

ReceivedDetails    ACCOUNTNO v="3275402GBP"
ReceivedDetails    AGR1
ReceivedDetails    AGR2
ReceivedDetails    PAY2
```

Note:
Records in Value Column is dynamic, We need to seperate the tags after the KEY tag

Can you help in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS is this and is the datatype XML for column `Value`?

Comment: Sql Server 2012, Datatype is Nvarchar for Value Column.

Comment: okkk so you are using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #tmp (MENUACTION NVARCHAR(100), VALUE NVARCHAR(100))
insert into #tmp (MENUACTION, VALUE) values (('ReceivedDetails'), ('<KEY /><ACCOUNTNO v="3275402GBP" /><AGR1 /><AGR2 /><PAY1 /><PAY2 />'));

with src as 
(
    select MENUACTION, cast(VALUE as XML) [xml]
    from #tmp
)
select src.MENUACTION
, cast(x.y.query('.') as nvarchar(100)) [VALUE_XML]
, x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') [VALUE_STR]
, x.y.value('@v', 'nvarchar(100)') [v_attribute]
from src
cross apply src.[xml].nodes('/*') as x(y)


drop table #tmp
```

Result:

```
MENUACTION      VALUE_XML                   VALUE_STR   v_attribute
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ReceivedDetails <KEY/>                      KEY         NULL
ReceivedDetails <ACCOUNTNO v="3275402GBP"/> ACCOUNTNO   3275402GBP
ReceivedDetails <AGR1/>                     AGR1        NULL
ReceivedDetails <AGR2/>                     AGR2        NULL
ReceivedDetails <PAY1/>                     PAY1        NULL
ReceivedDetails <PAY2/>                     PAY2        NULL
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1283f/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. How can I remove the tags for the XML in Value Column?

Comment: Great. You are a master. Thanks for your quick response.